# Swift: nil while unwrapping an Optional value. When trying to get user location

Tags: swift, ios8, coordinates, core-location, cllocationmanager

So I'm new to app development and I'm attempting to learn how user LocationManager works. My goal at this moment is to "ask for authorization" > check to see if it's authorized" > if true { get location and store coordinates in a variable }

here's my code:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var coordinates: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

aivRefresh.hidden = true

self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {


  locationManager.delegate = self
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
 }

}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!){



if locations != nil {

  var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate

  coordinates = "\(location.longitude),\(location.latitude)"
}
```

Comment: Which part of your code doesn't work?

Comment: I get nil with coordinates.

Comment: I don't understand why it's not placing the longitude and latitude in it.

Comment: Do you understand everything in this article and have you implemented all of that properly? http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Comment: yes. I have the requestWhenInUse key in my info.plist plus I request  Authorization after initializing my location manager.

Comment: I recently added the manager:didFailWithError: and i'm getting
Error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"